# How to make a string to a collection when parse a json

Tags: c#

I'm trying to access an API and got below response body with postman:

```
{
    "Name": "wangxiaoer",
    "Created": "2018-01-26T01:28:19.0388857Z",
    "Modified": "2019-06-18T03:46:52.4350569Z",
    "AdminSecurityGroups": "mhanch;sastrys;vinala;vballa",
    "DeveloperOwner": "sastrys;vballa",
    "ProgramManagerOwner": "sastrys",
    "Comments": null
}
```

I've used below code:

```
var content = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

to get the response body

I want to deserialize this content to an customized object like below:

```
class MyObject
{
   public string Name{get;set}

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AdminSecurityGroups")]
   public List<String> Admins { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DeveloperOwner")]
   public List<String> DevOwner { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProgramManagerOwner")]
   public List<String> PMOwner { get; set; }
}
```

Since the response content gives me each string which is made of multiple person's aliases by spliting with ';' for AdminSecurityGroups, DeveloperOwner, ProgramManagerOwner, so it could be better to convert each string to a list in order to reuse it later. I tried to define a list in the object instead of using String to store each of those parts, but when I use

```
MyObject my = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(content);
```

it throws exception.
Is there a way to implement converting a string to a list when parse json string using c#. For example:

```
"AdminSecurityGroups": "mhanch;sastrys;vinala;vballa"
```

it contains 4 people by spliting with ; when get the response string. Need to parse it to a list.

Comment: Use a converter https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBAU822AU822&sxsrf=ALeKk00gbwWUGAM00GakjTd2JGWeV8HhFA%3A1614295953906&ei=kTM4YM7sNpWO4-EPhbqXuAg&q=json+converter+C%23&oq=json+converter+C%23&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyAggAMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADICCAAyBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoHCAAQsAMQQzoECAAQQ1CzKViMMGDNM2gBcAJ4AIABtAGIAZYFkgEDMC40mAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCsABAQ&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiO-ZOHmYbvAhUVxzgGHQXdBYcQ4dUDCA0&uact=5

Comment: If you do not receive an array for those items, why don't you just change your model to be a string instead of a list? If you need a list elsewhere you can map that class to another that has list properties.

Comment: is this json.net or text.json ?

Comment: You're not receiving a real (json) enumeration in your json and instead just a string, that seems to have multiple values separated by ":".
Therefore you should also deserialize it as a string and then somehow extract the values and map it onto another class, as @Crowcoder already said.

Comment: Or just use a converter

Comment: If you are receiving that information via JSON from somewhere else, simple add additional read-only (non-JSON-serializable) properties that expose the information in those strings as `IEnumerable<string>`. There's no need for a custom coverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this multiple ways,

1. Normalize your json, json has arrays....
2. Deserialize to a string, then use another property to split it, or map to another property.
3. Just use a converter, which is built for this type of situation

**Json.Net**

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name{get; set; }

   [JsonProperty( "AdminSecurityGroups")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> Admins { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty( "DeveloperOwner")] 
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> DevOwner { get; set; }

   [JsonProperty( "ProgramManagerOwner")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> PMOwner { get; set; }
}

public class MyFunkConverter : JsonConverter<List<string>>
{
   public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<string> value, JsonSerializer serializer)
      => throw new NotImplementedException(); 
   public override List<string> ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<string> existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
      reader.Value.ToString().Split(';').ToList();
}

...

var result =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(input);
```

**Text.Json**

```
public class MyObject
{
   public string Name{get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("AdminSecurityGroups")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> Admins { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName("DeveloperOwner")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> DevOwner { get; set; }

   [JsonPropertyName( "ProgramManagerOwner")]
   [JsonConverter(typeof(MyFunkConverter))]
   public List<string> PMOwner { get; set; }
}

public class MyFunkConverter : System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter<List<string>>
{
   public override List<string>? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
      => reader.GetString().Split(';').ToList();
   public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, List<string> value, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
      => throw new NotImplementedException();
}

...

var result =  JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyObject>(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler way.  Just deserialize your JSON into an object and expose those strings as collections through read only properties.

This has the advantage of exposing the raw (*semi-colon-full*) strings as properties (if anyone wants to see them).  In fact, those I used your property names, I'd likely rename *Admins*, *DevOwner* and *PmOwner* to *AdminSecurityGroupsRaw*, *DeveloperOwnerRaw* and *ProgramManagerOwnerRaw* if this was my code.

First augment your `MyObject` class (I gave it a more descriptive name):

```
public class JsonStringToArrayObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "AdminSecurityGroups")]
    public string Admins { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "DeveloperOwner")]
    public string DevOwner { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ProgramManagerOwner")]
    public string PmOwner { get; set; }

    private List<string> _adminSecurityGroups = null;
    private List<string> _developerOwner = null;
    private List<string> _programManagerOwner = null;

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> AdminSecurityGroups
    {
        get
        {
            if (_adminSecurityGroups == null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Admins))
            {
                _adminSecurityGroups = Admins.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }

            return _adminSecurityGroups;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> DeveloperOwner
    {
        get
        {
            if (_developerOwner == null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DevOwner))
            {
                _developerOwner = DevOwner.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }

            return _developerOwner;
        }
    }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<string> ProgramManagerOwner
    {
        get
        {
            if (_programManagerOwner == null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PmOwner))
            {
                _programManagerOwner = PmOwner.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
            }

            return _programManagerOwner;
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON-exposed properties are the same.  But, I added read-only properties that expose the semi-colon separated strings as arrays.  The code for those getters is repeated three times, you may want to refactor that into a small worker function.

The code to exercise this is simple, first the JSON (I use single quotes - it's easier in C#):

```
private const string theJson = @"
{
    'Name': 'wangxiaoer',
    'Created': '2018-01-26T01:28:19.0388857Z',
    'Modified': '2019-06-18T03:46:52.4350569Z',
    'AdminSecurityGroups': 'mhanch;sastrys;vinala;vballa',
    'DeveloperOwner': 'sastrys;vballa',
    'ProgramManagerOwner': 'sastrys',
    'Comments': null
}";
```

and then this:

```
var jsonStringToArrayObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonStringToArrayObject>(theJson);
```

After that like of code executes, I can see the following in the debugger:

```
-   AdminSecurityGroups Count = 4   
    [0] "mhanch"    string
    [1] "sastrys"   string
    [2] "vinala"    string
    [3] "vballa"    string
```

and

```
-   DeveloperOwner  Count = 2   
    [0] "sastrys"   string
    [1] "vballa"    string
```

and

```
-   ProgramManagerOwner Count = 1   
    [0] "sastrys"   string
```

**Update**

That repeated code drove me nuts.  So I did a little refactoring, adding this private method to `JsonStringToArrayObject`:

```
private IEnumerable<string> GetterImplementation(ref List<string> privateField, string source)
{
    if (privateField == null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
    {
        privateField = source.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
    }

    return privateField;
}
```

Then the three read-only properties end up as:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public IEnumerable<string> AdminSecurityGroups => GetterImplementation(ref _adminSecurityGroups, Admins);

[JsonIgnore]
public IEnumerable<string> DeveloperOwner => GetterImplementation(ref _developerOwner, DevOwner);

[JsonIgnore]
public IEnumerable<string> ProgramManagerOwner => GetterImplementation(ref _programManagerOwner, PmOwner);
```

and everything works the same way.